# Сохранение фото и текста с помощью telebot, python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Вечер добрый, каким образом я могу сохранить в свой бот пересланное сообщение с канала, в посте есть картинка и текст, то есть это одно сообщение содержащее и картинку и текст к ней.

Я использую бибилиотеку `telebot`.

Само текстовое сообщение перехватываю с помощью `message.text`

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, в вопрос Ваш код.

Comment: Я принимаю текстовые сообщения этой строчкой `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`, а фото файлы `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])`, вопрос в том как я могу разом получить и картинку и текст

Answer (score 0):

Если сообщение содержит фото, используйте `message.caption` для получения текста